# "Client_Text_IO.File_Type must be declard" getting this error in PL/SQL Oracle form

Tags: oracle10g, plsqldeveloper, oracleforms

My line of codes are:

```
PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA IS

FILE_LOG    Client_Text_IO.File_Type;
LINE_LOG    VARCHAR(32767);
v_txt       varchar(32767);
v_counter number(12) := 0;

BEGIN

file_log :=  Client_Text_IO.fopen(file_upload.origin, 'r');

END;
```

I am wokring first time with Oracle form. I have no any idea about it. I have almost done my work but I am getting an error at compile time. Complete error description,

```
Error 201 at line 2, column 11
    identifier 'CLIENT_TEXT_IO.FILE_TYPE' must be declared
Error 0 at line 2, column 11
    Item ignored
Error 320 at line 12, column 2
    the declaration of the type of this expression is incomlete or malformed
Error 0 at line 12, column 2
    Statement ignored
Error 320 at line 14, column 3
    the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
Error 0 at line 14, column 3
    Statement ignored
Error 201 at line 20, column 6
    identifier 'V_TEXT' must be declared
Error 0 at line 20, column 3
    Statement ignored
Error 320 at line 24, column 24
    the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
Error 0 at line 30, column 2
    Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the webutil.pll library to the form.

Comment: yes, it is attached with my project @ compile time. But when I run it it's again producing en error. Can you guide me how can I provide this library @ run time.